# I want to trace a gps device

Tags: gps, geolocation

I want to create a device that should transmit its location to a server using anyother medium other than GSM. Bascially I need a tracking device which i could give to my worker and he goes to a forest or mine he should be traceable without using any other medium like GSM. I want the satellite to monitor him.

Please tell me way

Answer (score 2):

GPS is a passive format that works as a receiving unit only, you can have a second device such as a phone which then sends the signal to somewhere to track the GPS device, it is probably easier to buy an existing unit that does this then to make one, but you could use radio signals, does it need to be in real time or can the location be recorded for later analysis, also GPS signals won't work well under cover or in mines.  Google how GPS works